# How do you convert hex to decimal using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to convert hex to a decimal in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). Found several examples in C#, but when I tried to convert to VB.NET I was not successful. An example of a hexadecimal number that I am trying to convert is "A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E".

Comment: What number are you expecting? That is 192 bits... much bigger than most of the inbuilt types...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a 24-byte (192-bit) number; what value are you expecting?

Note that you can use `Convert` to do a lot of the grungy work here - for example (in C#):

```
    string hex = "A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E";
    byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length ; i++)
    {
        raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2,2), 16);
    }
```

How you get from `raw` to a number depends on what you think the number is...

Visual Basic translation courtesy of [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) (although the "-1" looks odd):

```
Dim hex As String = "A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E"
Dim raw As Byte() = New Byte((hex.Length / 2)  - 1) {}
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To raw.Length - 1
    raw(i) = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring((i * 2), 2), &H10)
Next i
```

Comment: I do not know what the number should be.  Lockhead Martin just started shipping this data and they have not finished the documentation.  We kind of in a discovery mode at this time.  Should I just sum up the Raw(i) values to get the numeric?

Comment: No; that would be bad... the problem is: what to do with 192 bits? that could be 3 longs (Int64), 6 ints (Int32), 2 decimals, one BigInteger, etc... but is it big-endian, little-endian, etc... decoding binary needs a *little* bit of knowledge about the source.

Comment: The -1 is correct, VB array declaration syntax gives the upper bound of the array whereas C# gives the number of items in the array. Since the array is zero based the upper bound is one less than the number of items.

Comment: Just to add, .NET's [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268268.aspx) structure should be able to ingest such a value easily via the `TryParse` method that lets you specify number styles.  That's a signed version, though.  So if your hex number is really unsigned, you might need to implement a small wrapper around BigInteger to handle the signed element, and then return it.

Answer (score 17):

For hex values which don't actually require a bignum class to work with, you can use the normal conversion function but prefix the number with "&H". VB interprets "&H" in the text as meaning "this is a hex number", just like it does in code.

```
dim n = Cint("&H" & text)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Val` function in Visual Basic to convert a hexadecimal value to a decimal value. This is done by prefixing the string with `"&H"`, to tell Visual Basic that this is a hexadecimal value, and then convert that into a number.

```
Dim Value As Integer = Val("&H" & YourHexadecimalStringHere)
```

Answer (score 5):

Tried the others replies and this was the one that worked for me:

```
    Convert.ToInt32(yourHEXString, 16)
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32)

Answer (score 1):

Write one yourself.

You will need to tokenize the string, then start from the right, and work your way left.

```
int weight = 1;
While Looping
{

  If (token(i) == "F") { DecimalValue += 15 * weight; }
  If (token(i) == "E") { DecimalValue += 14 * weight; }
  If (token(i) == "D") { DecimalValue += 13 * weight; }
  If (token(i) == "C") { DecimalValue += 12 * weight; }
  If (token(i) == "B") { DecimalValue += 11 * weight; }
  If (token(i) == "A") { DecimalValue += 10 * weight; }
  else { DecimalValue += token(i) * weight; }

  weight = weight * 16;
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim hex As String
    hex = "A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E"

    Dim dec As Long
    Dim hexpart As String
    For x As Integer = 1 To (hex.Length / 2)

        hexpart = hex.Substring((x * 2) - 2, 2)
        dec = Int32.Parse(hexpart, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)

        Debug.Print("Hex = " + hex + ",HexPart = " + hexpart + ", Dec = " + dec.ToString + Environment.NewLine)
    Next
```

This won't work for Decimal and the Hex is too long for integer... but you get the idea.  You could split it and recombine.

```
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = A1, Dec = 161
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 41, Dec = 65
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 52, Dec = 82
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 46, Dec = 70
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 4C, Dec = 76
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 20, Dec = 32
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 32, Dec = 50
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 30, Dec = 48
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 30, Dec = 48
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 42, Dec = 66
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 32, Dec = 50
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 32, Dec = 50
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 30, Dec = 48
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 20, Dec = 32
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 57, Dec = 87
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 2F, Dec = 47
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 54, Dec = 84
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 49, Dec = 73
Hex = A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E,HexPart = 47, Dec = 71
```

Answer (score 1):

This will convert your string into an array of bytes:

```
Dim hex As String = "A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E"

Dim len As Integer = hex.Length \ 2
Dim data(len - 1) As Byte
For i As Integer = 0 to len - 1
   data(i) = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Function toByte(ByVal Shex As String) As List(Of Byte)
    Const cvtCH As Integer = 2
    Dim retval As New List(Of Byte)
    Dim rmndr As Integer
    rmndr = Shex.Length Mod cvtCH
    If rmndr <> 0 Then Shex = Shex.PadLeft(Shex.Length + cvtCH - rmndr, "0"c)
    For x As Integer = 0 To Shex.Length - 1 Step cvtCH
        retval.Add(Convert.ToByte(Shex.Substring(x, cvtCH), 16))
    Next
    Return retval
End Function
Private Function toU32(ByVal Shex As String) As List(Of UInt32)
    Const cvtCH As Integer = 8
    Dim retval As New List(Of UInt32)
    Dim rmndr As Integer
    rmndr = Shex.Length Mod cvtCH
    If rmndr <> 0 Then Shex = Shex.PadLeft(Shex.Length + cvtCH - rmndr, "0"c)
    For x As Integer = 0 To Shex.Length - 1 Step cvtCH
        retval.Add(Convert.ToUInt32(Shex.Substring(x, cvtCH), 16))
    Next
    Return retval
End Function
Private Function toU64(ByVal Shex As String) As List(Of UInt64)
    Const cvtCH As Integer = 16
    Dim retval As New List(Of UInt64)
    Dim rmndr As Integer
    rmndr = Shex.Length Mod cvtCH
    If rmndr <> 0 Then Shex = Shex.PadLeft(Shex.Length + cvtCH - rmndr, "0"c)
    For x As Integer = 0 To Shex.Length - 1 Step cvtCH
        retval.Add(Convert.ToUInt64(Shex.Substring(x, cvtCH), 16))
    Next
    Return retval
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'unsigned 32 bit max = FFFFFFFF
    'unsigned 64 bit max = FFFFFFFF
    'signed 32 bit max = 7FFFFFFF
    'signed 64 bit max = 7FFFFFFF
    Dim hexS As String = "A14152464C203230304232323020572F544947455234352E"
    Dim hexS2 As String = "A14152464C203230304232323020572F54494745523435"
    toByte(hexS)
    toU32(hexS)
    toU64(hexS)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim hex As String = "A1B2C3D4"
Dim int As Integer = Val("&H" & hex)
```