# How to print 0x00000001 from 1

Tags: c#, hex

Good day!
How to print value with

```
Console.Writeline()
```

- int value as hex:
  For example: 1-> 0x000...01;

Thank you!

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/c-sharp-convert-integer-to-hex-and-back-again

Comment: JGeerWM's answer in the linked duplicate answers your question.

Comment: @Heinzi [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642417/how-do-you-convert-hex-to-decimal-using-vb-net) is a much better duplicate than the one you provided, perhaps change it to that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = 1;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("X8"));
```

'8' stands for the number of digits you want to show with hex number.