# Negative result in HEX to DEC vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hex, decimal

Need help in converting hex to dec in VB.NET

I use the code below in smaller number which returns the expected result.

```
leftPaddingHex = Val("&H" & "99000533")
```

but when using 99000533 it return negative result -1728051917. I am expecting to get 2566915379. I am using to get the correct result in ms sql. using the code below.

```
CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(varbinary(4),(SELECT master.dbo.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin(@leftPadding))))
```

Need help on this. Thanks in advance.

Thank you.

Aze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Val` method returns `Double`. This cannot be changed

One workaround would be to use `Long` data type in the final result (that is, your `leftPaddingHex`) and to check if the result in the intermediate stage is negative, we add it with `UInt.MaxValue + 1` to correct it:

```
Dim leftPaddingHex As Long = Val("&H" & "99000533")
If leftPaddingHex < 0 Then
  leftPaddingHex = leftPaddingHex + UInt32.MaxValue + 1
End If
```

For hexadecimal with even larger number, I suggest you to take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642417/how-do-you-convert-hex-to-decimal-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 3):

I just thought that I'd post this alternate method.

The various integer type's `Parse` and `TryParse` methods allow you to specify a [System.Globalization.NumberStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter.  You can specify the `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` to parse a hexadecimal string.  The only restriction is that the string can not be prefixed with "0x" or "&h".

```
 Dim unsigned32 As UInt32
 Dim itParsed As Boolean = UInt32.TryParse("99000533", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, Nothing, unsigned32)
```