# Convert HEX to Double in VB

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have been searching for function to convert HEX to Double using VB. I found only how to do it in C. Can anyone help?

At the moment, I only have hex to single using vb.

Comment: `I only have hex to single using vb.` - so replace in that code the word `Single` with the word `Double`?

Comment: visit this
[for solving your problem,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642417/how-do-you-convert-hex-to-decimal-using-vb-net)

Comment: Post the C, and your attempt at translating it to VB and we'll help

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution edited out of their question:

> Finally [found a working function] to convert the hex to double:

```
Function HexToDouble(s As String) As Double
    Try
        Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)
        For i As Integer = s.Length - 2 To 0 Step -2
            bytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16))
        Next
        Return BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes.ToArray, 0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New FormatException("The supplied hex value is either empty or in an incorrect format. Use the following format: 0000", ex)
    End Try
End Function
```